# Custom AuthenticationProvider not getting called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing a spring boot 2 application.I am trying to implement spring security for that.I have used a custom AutenticationProvider for that.But it is not getting called .Spring authentication is working however. please help me to resolve this issue.I have tried many ways,but it wont worked.I am using jwt to create tokens .

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation class

```
@Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
@Autowired
private SecurmailSecurityProvider provider;
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.authenticationProvider( getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider());
}
@Bean
protected AuthenticationProvider getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new SecurmailSecurityProvider();
}
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
    authenticationProvider(provider).
    authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(MessageController.URL_AUTHENTICATE).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class);
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

Custom Authentication provider class

```
    @Component
@Primary
public class SecurmailSecurityProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
MessageClientRepository clientRepo;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) return authentication;

    SmAuthenticationToken token = (SmAuthenticationToken) authentication;

    if (token.getGuid() != null && !token.getGuid().trim().isEmpty()) {
        MessageClient client = clientRepo.findByGuid(token.getGuid());
        if (client != null) {               
            return new SmAuthenticationToken(client);
    }


}
    return null;
}
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (SmAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already you autowired the CustomAuthentication provider by using

```
@Autowired
private SecurmailSecurityProvider provider;
```

again you are creating bean and passing that CustomAuthentication provider

```
@Bean
protected AuthenticationProvider getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new SecurmailSecurityProvider();
}
```

Instead below code

```
@Autowired
private SecurmailSecurityProvider provider;
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.authenticationProvider( getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider());
}
@Bean
protected AuthenticationProvider getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new SecurmailSecurityProvider();
}
```

Use this code

```
@Autowired
private SecurmailSecurityProvider provider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.authenticationProvider(provider);
}
```

And also Custom Authentication Provider implementation should be like this below:

```
@Component
public class SecurmailSecurityProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {

            // use the credentials
            // and authenticate against the third-party system
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying: `Cannot resolve method 'shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem'`